# Moment of Inertia of combined bodies (cube inside hollow cylinder)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

> What is the moment of inertia of a hollow cylinder of radius $R$ inside which a cube of face diagonal $2R$ is placed about the axis passing through the axis of the cylinder? Both have same mass $m$.

I just added the individual moment of inertia of the two bodies as $$ I = mR^2 + \frac{m(\sqrt2R)^2}{6} = \frac{4mR^2}{3}$$Is this correct?

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is correct, since $I = \int{r^2 . dm}$(which is just a number), the moment of inertia of both objects can be added up.